# How to write a .phpstorm.meta.php file for CommandBus

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using a command bus in my project and it works fine except for code completion.

In PhpStorm I always need to hint what will be the type of result from it.
So recently I decided to make a `.phpstorm.meta.php` file that will handle the code completion typehints for me.

This is what I made based on documentation I found here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#map

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(\Acme\BusBundle\Service\QueryBusWrapperInterface::dispatch(0), map([
       \App\Query\Action\User\GetUserById => App\Model\User\UserInterface,
    ]));
}
```

For reference, here is how this command bus is being used:

```
class A
{
    protected $queryBus;

    public function __construct(QueryBusWrapperInterface $queryBus)
    {
        $this->queryBus = $queryBus;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        $userId = 1; // Get it from somewhere

        /** @var UserInterface $user */
        $user = $this->queryBus->dispatch(new GetUserById($userId));

        $user-> // PhpStorm should hint here
    }
}
```

Problem is, that it does not seem to work at all. If I remove the `@var` comment PhpStorm no longer hints anything.

Could someone hint me towards what am I doing wrong.
Am I missing something in the meta file?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to work, unfortunately.

You can :

- Either use the argument type as the method return type directly (with `type(0)`);
- Or you can take the literal value of the argument (a string) and use map() to bind it a certain return type (like `map(["myString" => \My\Other\Type::class])`). Please note that both the key and the value are strings here.

What you can't do is to take the type of the argument (`new GetUserById()` in your case) and assign different return types depending on what type that is.

I couldn't find an existing request for that on our tracker, so maybe it's worth submitting one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI